# SQL JOIN Query's to collect data for two columns

Tags: mysql, pdo

One of my tables has a column named "t_name" which supplies an exact name (ie: Google)

And another table has two columns named

m_team_home and m_team_away

Both m_team_home and m_team_away would be INT's in the database but would grab the name from the first table. My joined query is only able to grab the home's team name, and I don't know how to get the away team's name because it will output the same thing.

I know it may be hard to explain, but much help would be appreciated.

Comment: show what u try? the db structure

Comment: @Cameron if you wouldn't mind marking my answer as accepted since it solved your issue I would appreciate it and we can have this question marked as resolved

Answer (score 1, accepted):

sounds like you want to join on the table twice

```
SELECT a.team, a1.team
FROM table t
JOIN another_table a on a.m_team_home = t.id -- t.id or whatever is in that table that maps to the home / away teams
JOIN another_table a1 on a1.m_team_away = t.id
```

that way you can get the name for the home team and away team.. you may want to consider making those LEFT joins just incase one doesn't exist and it gets filtered out

Comment: how do I exactly output that in an associative array though via PDO's fetch? I assign the array to smarty and then output it that way.

Comment: @CameronSwyft I honestly cant help you without any data or anything... I'm working off of theory here since thats all you've provided... you should be able to select the home team name and away team name with that query though

Comment: Is there a way we can go into a private chat on here and discuss?

Comment: Well, can we go into the chat then?